# Should calls to a Content Resolver be done in a Service (i.e separate thread)?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm learning more about content providers in Android and they're performance. For example, if I write my own content provider (subclass ContentProvider) for SQLite operations and then I want to do an operation in an Activity's onPause() method, then in my Activity I would do:

```
@Override
protected void onPause (){
    super.onPause();

    // ...prepare myTransactionValues

    // This could be anything like insert, bulkInsert, query, delete, etc.
    getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, myTransactionValues)
}
```

However, it looks likes this database operation is being done on the main thread. Is the work being done in a separate thread behind the scenes? Should it be in it's own thread? If it should, is there a recommended way (perhaps a Service)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something in a Non-UI thread, you should usually use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). A `service`, on the other hand, is best kept for long tasks.

Comment: Why AsyncTask as opposed to a Service?

Comment: @BigAndy, `AsyncTask`s are designed to run in a non-UI thread, but can update the UI while it is running. This is really beneficial for giving the user feedback. A service, on the other hand, cannot update the UI thread until the task is complete. I should update my response however. I will add that a `service` is good for long tasks, such as downloading an image from a remote server.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. So to answer my original question, you're saying that Content Resolver calls are not running in their own threads behind the scenes. So the recommended way to call them would be to put them in an AsyncTask wrapper rather than a Service. This would allow updating of the UI without bogging down the UI thread performance. Correct?

Comment: Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations, you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.
link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I too searched a lot online and found out that actually SQLite methods e.g., insert,delete etc. all run on the Thread where they are called as opposed to the concept that they under the hood create separate threads to do the same which finally means that THE DEVELOPER IS RESPONSIBLE FOR CREATING SEPARATE THREADS TO DO DATABASE OPERATIONS .

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use Content Providers is in `AsyncTask` because they are expensive operations that can't run in the main thread. 
Android have encapsulated this pattern in what they call loaders they extend `AsyncTaskLoader` for do the job in a non UI thread use loaders callbacks and Cursors for retrieve data from the content provider.