# Android Volley SQLite integration/combination

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-volley

I want to integrate Volley into my project. But there is a problem with saving data to sqlite database. Is it ok to do the saving actions in activity (where I get the response from web service) or how it is better to use loader pattern here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a threading perspective you probably don't want to write the change to the database on your main UI thread in Android, best to do it in a separate thread. I believe the result from Volley is always returned ON the main UI thread (See ResponseDeliveryRunnable class in Volley for details).

This means you may want to use an Executor or perhaps the following code to hop off the Main UI thread in your Response.Listener:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // database insert here 
  }
});
```

Really it depends on the structure of your application, do you have a DAO layer and domain objects or are you using direct SQL statements to insert data from the web service straight into your database? Personally I use greenDAO ORM which gives me domain objects and a DAO and simply make sure when working with the database for inserts/deletes/updates I am always off the Android Main UI thread.

Comment: I'm using contentproviders to work with databаse. Is it ok to use ContentResolver in Activity or better do it in AsyncTask?

Comment: This question confirms my suggestion of AsyncTask is a good solution with a ContentProvider - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392012/should-calls-to-a-content-resolver-be-done-in-a-service-i-e-separate-thread